Return HREF by searching through parent element -Selenium Python
i'm fairly new to coding/selenium
I am trying to get a list of href links by searching through one of its parent element
I believe i need to do this as the website has a heap of copies of the link, so searching for any href will give me a very long list of copies.
Ideally, i would like it to make a list of links
Ive been stuck on this for a few hours, so happy with any sort of help
I tried this
links = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[@data-testid="card-container"//a[@href]')

Link to the website:
https://www.airbnb.com.au/s/Gold-Coast--QLD/homes?place_id=ChIJt2BdK0cakWsRcK_e81qjAgM&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&checkin=2024-12-22&checkout=2024-12-28&date_picker_type=calendar&adults=9&children=2&pets=1&search_type=user_map_move&tab_id=home_tab&query=Gold%20Coast%2C%20QLD&flexible_trip_lengths%5B%5D=one_week&monthly_start_date=2024-08-01&monthly_length=3&monthly_end_date=2024-11-01&search_mode=regular_search&price_filter_input_type=2&price_filter_num_nights=6&channel=EXPLORE&ne_lat=-27.8312213554841&ne_lng=153.85466017727208&sw_lat=-28.314709414353157&sw_lng=153.3574718233147&zoom=10.257561001998951&zoom_level=10.257561001998951&search_by_map=true&price_min=8683&price_max=14459&min_bedrooms=5


Your usecase is to get multiple elements
So use driver.find_elements instead of driver.find_element

Xpath mentioned above has incorrect brackets
use this //div[@data-testid="card-container"]//a[@href]

My suggestion would be to try this :
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//descendant::div[@data-testid="card-container"]//a[@href]')



I just tried this. It doesnt seem to be grabbing the link.
After this, I tried to print the list of links, and it was just a list of blank entries

This is the sample script i tried with above xpath, I am getting 28 elements in list  https://paste.opensuse.org/pastes/c22451af6795
